# Android, viewpager, each layout has own activity

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, multiscreen

I have 4 screens (4 layouts and 4 activities). Here is the code how I'am switching it:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return new DetailFragment();
    case 1:
        return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    case 2:
        return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.b);
    case 3:
        return new CompFragment(R.drawable.b);

    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when I add onClick method in comp layout and CompFragment activity it still trying execute method from MainActivity (and display error method not found):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Button" />
```

I want to layout has own activity. How to do this ?

**EDIT:**
CompFragment extends Fragment not FragmentActivity

```
public class CompFragment extends Fragment {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I  want to layout has own activity. How to do this ?

You do not do this, as this is not supported. If you do not want the button click to go to the activity, get rid of the `android:onClick` attribute, and have your fragment call `setOnClickListener()` on the `Button` instead.